# Installing yum packages by pattern

Tags: rhel, yum

I want to install all openoffice packages. Passing openoffice* obviously wouldn't work, because it'd look at file system. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

You can use shell globbing patterns as package names:

> If no package matches the given package name(s), they are assumed to be a shell glob and any matches are then installed.

(from [yum(8)](http://man.cx/yum%288%29))

But you have to make sure that your shell does not consume your glob:

```
# yum install 'openoffice*'
```

Without the single quotes the shell expands the glob if your directory contains files whose filenames begin with 'openoffice'.

### Alternative (inspect package list)

You can query all installable package that match `openoffice*` via:

```
$ yum list available 'openoffice*'
```

To extract those package names you can use `repoquery`:

```
$ repoquery --qf='%{name}' --pkgnarrow=available 'openoffice*'
```

Thus you could install those packages via:

```
# xargs yum install < output_from_prev_command.log
```

(Those steps give you the chance to inspect the list of all 'openoffice*' matching packages, e.g. to remove obvious unwanted packages.)

Comment: Note that instead of using "yum list available" (which is meant to be UI and not necessarily usable from sed) you are _much_ better off using repoquery --pkgnarrow=available.

Comment: @JamesAntill, thanks for the hint, updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... I've checked it and

```
yum install openoffice*
```

works properly (wildcard is accepted)

Comment: The * should be escaped, or it could match a file in the current directory containing "openoffice" in its name.

Comment: also works with `yum update a* b* c*`